# Opening a dialog on slack via a google cloud function

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-cloud-functions, slack-api

I'm using this [Slack Client](https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk) to interact with the Slack api. I'm trying to open a dialog box on slack when the user uses the following command `/openForm`. I am also using **google cloud functions** to handle this functionality.

Heres my code:

```
exports.openForm = (req, res) => {
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(response => {
      return req.body;
    })
    .then(response => {
      const slack = new slackModel();
      const dialogObj = {
        trigger_id: response.trigger_id,
        dialog: {
          callback_id: "ryde-46e2b0",
          title: "Request a Ride",
          submit_label: "Request",
          notify_on_cancel: true,
          state: "Limo",
          elements: [
            {
              type: "text",
              label: "Pickup Location",
              name: "loc_origin"
            },
            {
              type: "text",
              label: "Dropoff Location",
              name: "loc_destination"
            }
          ]
        }
      };

      return slack.openForm(dialogObj);
    })
    .then(data => Promise.resolve(data));
};
```

Heres my Slack Model Class:

```
import { WebClient } from "@slack/web-api";

export class SlackModel {
  web: WebClient;
  constructor(message: string) {
    this.web = new WebClient(SLACK_TOKEN_HERE);
  }

  openForm(dialogObj): any {
    return this.web.dialog.open(dialogObj);
}
```

What am I doing wrong, the dialog won't open, I get a **Error: could not handle the request** error.

I have checked my TOKEN and it's correct. Can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Something looks wrong with this fragment of code:

```
exports.openForm = (req, res) => {
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(response => {
      return req.body;
    })
    .then(response => {
      const slack = new slackModel();
```

If we look specifically at:

```
.then(response => {
  return req.body;
})
```

what follows this is another `.then()` which implies that what you return (`req.body`) is itself a promise ... but to the best of my knowledge, it isn't.  Its either going to be a string or a buffer that was passed into the function.